# org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Undefined name:

Tags: serialization, avro

For converting generics to avro schema i use the below annotation , but I get the exception after that

```
    public class Test2<T>
    {
@AvroSchema("{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":[\"null\",\"Test4\"]}")
    private Set<T> test4;
}

public class Test4 {

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Integer x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Test4(Integer x) {

        this.x = x;
    }

    public Test4() {

    }

    private Integer x;
}
```

The error I get here is 
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Undefined name:Test4

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked

```
    @AvroSchema("{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"name\":\"Child\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"x\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}}")
```

Thanks btw.